# Scaling center item in RecyclerView

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

When scrolling in a RecyclerView, I want to achieve something like this:
[image]

Where the center item is scaled bigger than the other items. I've found a way to scale all the items, or what is called a Carousel Effect. But that is not what I want. I want to scale only the center item, and keep the other items their default size.

this is what I've found on other answers:

```
override fun onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView: RecyclerView) {
    val snapHelper = LinearSnapHelper()
    snapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView)

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
            val layoutManager = recyclerView.layoutManager!!
            val midpoint = layoutManager.width / 2f
            val distance = shrinkDistance * midpoint

            for (i in 0 until layoutManager.childCount) {
                val child = layoutManager.getChildAt(i)!!
                val childMidpoint = (layoutManager.getDecoratedRight(child) + layoutManager.getDecoratedLeft(child)) / 2f
                val d = Math.min(distance, Math.abs(midpoint - childMidpoint))
                val scale = 1 + -shrinkAmount * d / distance
                child.scaleX = scale
                child.scaleY = scale
            }
        }
    })
}
```

As I said, this scales all the visible items, where I only want to zoom the center item.

Comment: what is shrink amount here?

Answer (score -1):

You could give the middle child different scaling.

Calculate the middle child from childCount and use a different scaling for it than the others.

Comment: Yes, but I also next to know if the next child is right off left, and rescale the old child